# Update and redirect other paginate

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working with ionic in a single application. Data consuming a WS get them on my server. I'm doing an UPDATE data both in my database server and data stored in session within my app. This operation is correct and there is no problem in the update, however I would like to update the data within the entire application, for this I use a maintainer of obtaining and data initialization.

```
.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        set: function(key, value) {
            return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        },
        get: function(key) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        },
        destroy: function(key) {
            return localStorage.removeItem(key);
        },
    };
}])
```

In the home to display user data I do the following:

```
$scope.user_nombres = sessionService.get('user_nombres') + " " + sessionService.get('user_apellidos');
```

This works well. When I update my server, I make a post to a URL, it updates the data in my DB and returns me the new data. I use my factory for the data again in September and finally redirect to home.

```
sessionService.set("user_nombres", data.UpdateUsuarioResult.nombres);
sessionService.set("user_apellidos", data.UpdateUsuarioResult.apellidos);
$location.path('/app/home');
```

However, THIS IF updated my data, but to redirect with $ location.path or $ state.go, the data within the controller Home, have not been updated and also, I navigation to return to Edit profile, which I do not want. I do not want from home you can return to a previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a $watch in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return sessionService.get('user_nombres') + " " + sessionService.get('user_apellidos');
}, function(user_nombres){
  $scope.user_nombres = user_nombres;
});
```